# Python loop through all urls in CSS file and replace

Tags: python, css, string, url, substring

I'm trying to find all relative urls in a css file and replace them with absolute url. I know how to get the absolute path but first I need to find all occurances of the url() in the file, then grab the relative path and replace it with absolute path. Here is what I tried so far.

Given my Css is:

```
css= "background:url(/pub-assets/img/index/sec8-bg.png)
src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3')
background-image:url('../img/index/blok1-bg.jpg')"
```

Im trying this code:

```
start = "url("
end = ")"
print css[css.find(start)+len(start):css.rfind(end)]
```

but it does not return the url and instead is returning css code sadly.
Can anyone help me with this. Any suggestion much appreciated

Comment: There are 3 URLs in this string; you are asking to find the start of the first and the end of the last.

Comment: I need to get url that is between url(). I have a huge css file and this is one example of url structures that I have.

Comment: You are reading the whole file at once, you should read line by line instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expressions, you can list every urls easily. Like that :

```
import re

css= "background:url(/pub-assets/img/index/sec8-bg.png) \n src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3') \n background-image:url('../img/index/blok1-bg.jpg')"

re.findall(r'url\((.*?)\)', css)
```

## Output :

```
['/pub-assets/img/index/sec8-bg.png',
 "'../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3'",
 "'../img/index/blok1-bg.jpg'"]
```

If you want the indices, you can use findIter instead of findall https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer :

```
[(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(r'url\((.*?)\)', css)]
```

## Output

```
[(11, 49), (56, 103), (123, 155)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will print each of the URLs, assuming there aren't any stray parentheses in the string:

```
start = "url("
end = ")"
txt = css
start_pos = txt.find(start)
while start_pos >= 0:
    end_pos = txt.find(end)
    print(txt[start_pos+len(start):end_pos])
    txt = txt[end_pos+len(end):]
    start_pos = txt.find(start)
```

Comment: Thanks. this answer is also correct by I like @pensfute answer more.

Comment: I like it more, too.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions, something like:

```python
import re

// ? = non-greedy
result = re.search( "url\(.+?\)", css)
print result.groups()
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can also do it like this:**

1) I altered the regex from [pensflute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49819739/8970591) a bit, so it doesn't also grab the literal images, like "url(data:image/png.." which are itself an image and therefore not externally loaded. And also some websites don't use quotes (' ') to wrap the urls since it will also work without, so I also added those as optional in the regex.

2) Than I am removing the duplicates from the list I generated, which is needed when you're replacing the urls in the next part.

3) Lastly I am looping through the list of urls than need to be replaced with their absolute urls, and using the urljoin() function to achieve this.
This will also resolve all links to the right format even if they're from 1 level higher, like "../images/someimg.png"

4) And than finally you have your modified CSS where all the urls are absolute :)

```
import re
from urllib.parse import urljoin

cssUrl = 'https://www.example.nl/static/bundles/css/someApp.css'
css= "background:url(/pub-assets/img/index/sec8-bg.png) \n src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3') \n background-image:url('../img/index/blok1-bg.jpg') \n  .grabbing{cursor:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAO0lEQVQ4y2NgGHbgPxTjY+PWDAP42PgM+k8IwNRQZAg+A/5TYsB/UgBFBtDM/0QZQkxawGsI3QygLwAAbjZlqS88cqkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) 8 8,move}"

# 1) Find all css links
links = re.findall(r'url\(\'?([(..)/].*?)\'?\)', css)

# 2) Clear all duplicates
links = list(dict.fromkeys(links))

# print(links)
# 3) Replace all links with the absolute path
for link in links:
    css = css.replace(link, urljoin(cssUrl, link))

# 4) Print out the modified css
print(css)
```

Which **outputs this**:

```
background:url(https://www.example.nl/pub-assets/img/index/sec8-bg.png) 
src:url('https://www.example.nl/static/bundles/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3') 
background-image:url('https://www.example.nl/static/bundles/img/index/blok1-bg.jpg')
.grabbing{cursor:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAO0lEQVQ4y2NgGHbgPxTjY+PWDAP42PgM+k8IwNRQZAg+A/5TYsB/UgBFBtDM/0QZQkxawGsI3QygLwAAbjZlqS88cqkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) 8 8,move}
```